# Graphics Device Initialization failed for :es2, sw in Linux

Tags: linux, java-8, javafx-8

I tried all the listed solutions available in stackoverflow.com and askubuntu.com .I am using java-8 not the defalult jdk available.I really hope someone could provide me a solution and let me know if the question is not much relevant.

**Java Env:**

```
java version "1.8.0_144"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.144-b01, mixed mode)
```

**Error:**

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; support was removed in 8.0
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:221)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:205)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:217)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:209)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:337)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
```